# Recursive function leads to simplifier loop in Isabelle

Tags: recursion, isabelle, theorem-proving

I have the following two Isabelle definitions:

```
fun remove_left :: "cmd ⇒ cmd × cmd option" where
"remove_left (Comp c d) = (case remove_left c of
  (head, Some c') ⇒ (head, Some (Comp c' d)) |
  (head, None) ⇒ (head, Some d)
)" |
"remove_left c = (c, None)"

function pop_flatten :: "cmd ⇒ cmd" where
"pop_flatten c = (case remove_left c of
  (h, Some c') ⇒ Comp h (pop_flatten c') |
  (h, None) ⇒ h
)"
by pat_completeness auto
termination by(relation "measure size"; simp; metis remove_left_decreases)
```

(As an exercise I am proving that various versions of program flattening routines are equal.)

The simplifier seems unable to handle this. For example, when I try the following obviously false lemma:

```
lemma "pop_flatten c = Skip"
  apply(simp)
```

The simplifier immediately goes into a loop. simp_trace shows it is continuously applying the definition of pop_flatten. My suspicion is that the case expression introduces the term c' which the simplifier considers to be completely new, so it unfolds the definition again. I am unsure how to work around this, I would like to not change my definition. I tried removing the simp rules for pop_flatten as follows:

```
declare pop_flatten.simps [simp del]
```

But now several proof steps which I would normally do `by simp` obviously don't work anymore. My definition of cmd is standard, just a skip, sequential composition, if and while. Is there indeed an edge case in the simplifier I am running into here, or is my definition just wrong in some way I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not particularly surprising that this leads to an infinite loop: The left-hand side of the `pop_flatten.simps` rules is immediately applicable to its right-hand side again, so you are almost guaranteed an infinite rewrite loop.

For that reason, if you do a recursive definitions with just a single equation that isn't guarded by a condition or a pattern match, it is best to immediately delete the `.simps` rule from the simp set (as you have done).

If you do want to apply it, you can either apply it once in a very targeted way using `apply (subst pop_flatten.simps)` or you can restrict it to the particular value you want to apply it to, e.g. `apply (simp add: pop_flatten.simps[of c])`.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, after Manuel's suggestion, what I wound up doing was rewriting `pop_flatten` to have a case split in the preconditions as follows:

```
function pop_flatten' :: "cmd ⇒ cmd" where
"snd (remove_left c) = None ⟹ pop_flatten' c = fst (remove_left c)" |
"snd (remove_left c) ≠ None ⟹ pop_flatten' c = Comp (fst (remove_left c)) (pop_flatten' (the (snd (remove_left c))))"
by simp auto
termination
  apply(relation "measure size")
   apply(simp)
  apply(simp add: remove_left_decreases)
  by (metis option.sel prod.collapse remove_left_decreases)
```

I don't know exactly, but my suspicion is that this is better for the simplifier because the unfolding is now guarded by a `⟹` condition. Apparently the simplifier *is* allowed to punch through the `case of` construct (?), which was thus my faulty assumption.

I then reproved my lemmas using this version, which all became massively simpler because I could use `simp` instead of having to custom design terms to be substituted, and in the end (after proving equality of `pop_flatten` and `pop_flatten'`) substituted the `simp`-unfriendly version in there to get the final lemma. I guess this is not always an option but as my functions were pretty simple I did not have to change anything else.

(Thanks a bunch Manuel!)

Comment: The disadvantage of doing it this way is that the function will not be executable unless you then prove something like the original version as a code equation again. I would suggest using your original definition, deleting the offending rule from the simp set, and proving more convenient rules (like the ones you use as a definition now) as derived rules and add them to the simpset. That's what I usually do.