# Option that is some, let and case of cause rewriter not to simplify

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

In Isabelle, I have to following proof state:

```
proof (prove)
using this:
  find (λc. length c = 1) f = Some [l]

goal (1 subgoal):
 1. fst (units_propagate f) = fst (units_propagate (update_formula f (atom_of l) (is_pos l)))
```

I'm pretty sure this is true, if you combine the hypothesis with some simplification. To illustrate this, I can rewrite the `units_propagate f` call using HOL-Library.Rewrite:

```
apply(rewrite at "units_propagate f" units_propagate.simps)
===========================================================
proof (prove)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. find (λc. length c = 1) f = Some [l] ⟹
    fst (case find (λc. length c = 1) f of None ⇒ (f, Map.empty)
         | Some [l] ⇒
             let (f', e) = units_propagate (update_formula f (atom_of l) (is_pos l))
             in (f', e(atom_of l ↦ is_pos l))) =
    fst (units_propagate (update_formula f (atom_of l) (is_pos l)))
```

Now I'm pretty sure that if you use the hypothesis, the `case of` expression would simplify to only the `Some` case. Then, the use of `fst` allows keeping only the first element of the tuple, leading to the following proof state (hypothetical, as I cannot produce it):

```
proof (prove)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. find (λc. length c = 1) f = Some [l] ⟹
    fst (units_propagate (update_formula f (atom_of l) (is_pos l))) =
    fst (units_propagate (update_formula f (atom_of l) (is_pos l)))
```

And clearly this is equal. Since I can write these steps down, I'd expect that a call of simp should be able to solve it. But it cannot. Using `try`, after a relatively long time, it finds the following invocation:

```
by (metis (no_types, lifting) case_prod_unfold fst_conv list.simps(4) list.simps(5) option.simps(5))
```

And that works. But this was quite painful and I don't understand it. Can someone shed a light upon why this is difficult?

My suspicion is that Isabelle is having trouble unifying the `= Some [l]` assumption with the `l` created in the process of simplifying away the `case of` expression. But I don't know how I would indicate to Isabelle that these two variables should be merged. In case it matters, here is the full definition of `units_propagate`:

```
function (sequential) units_propagate :: "'a formula ⇒ 'a formula × 'a env" where
"units_propagate f =
  (case find (λc. length c = 1) f of
      Some [l] ⇒ 
        let (f', e) = units_propagate (update_formula f (atom_of l) (is_pos l)) in
        (f', e(atom_of l ↦ is_pos l))
    | None ⇒ (f, Map.empty)
)"
  by(simp_all)
termination
  apply(relation "measure size_formula")
   apply(simp)
  using update_formula_decreases_units_propagate by auto
```

EDIT: Okay, after staring at the `metis` call a bit I managed to mangle it into the following proof script for inspection:

```
    apply(simp only: case_prod_unfold)
    apply(simp only: option.simps)
    apply(simp only: list.simps)
    apply(meson fstI)
    done
```

And indeed it seems to peel of all the data types layer by layer. But I feel like normally isabelle has no problem punching through my layering of datatypes. But here it seems hard. Can someone explain why? Is there a way to restructure my function in a way that isabelle has an easier time with it?

Comment: My first try would be to try with "split: option.splits" to allow the simplifier to split the case for options. Your unit propagation is bad for the simplifier, because it cannot unpeal it (it is not terminating if you always split the case). I think I would change the definition of unit_propagation to take two arguments, the formula and the model. Then you can have a definition without let.

Comment: Remark that your definition is deterministic (you cannot pick the literal to propagate next)

Comment: Combined with some restructuring as suggested by Manuel in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76128977/recursive-function-leads-to-simplifier-loop-in-isabelle I can now work nicely with `units_propagate` and lemmas like it again. Thanks for your help! If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it. It's unfortunate that the answer to this question is "refactor your code" but I guess it's natural that there are better and worse designs for Isabelle.